# Best practice editing theme's plugin files

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor

I am currently making various changes to some of the .css and .php files that have been copied to the child theme of our parent theme.

Found that some files I need to edit reside in plugin folders outside theme - wp-content/uploads/ and wp-content/plugins.

My understanding is that I should not make edits directly to the plugin files so I am wondering what is best practice to edit these files without effecting future updates that could overwrite my changes?

I am stuck at not knowing what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and safest way is backing up the plugins folder manually.

1. Go to your Cpanel. Open wp-content and find "plugins" folder there.
2. Left click and create a ZIP of the plugins folder (put a date in the name so you remember)
3. Proceed to edit the plugin files
4. If something goes wrong, delete the plugin folder and simple extract the files you had zipped and change the extracted folder name to "plugins" (the correct name).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ENN9. That would be one way but I would isolate the edited files to transfer back rather than whole folder in instance of theme update.

Comment: That can lead up to errors and miscalculations. I would still advise that always backup and restore the entire plugins folder, not just the parts you edited. It is always safer that way.

Comment: If plugins have been updated in a theme update then to restore the entire plugin folder from a backup would result in overwriting the new files?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you can still update the plugins individually from WordPress dashboard after you upload the old backups. Also, plugins do not get automatically updated anyway, you have to update them from dashboard, so no extra effort will be needed.